# Terminate DebugActiveProcess or other debugging routines

Tags: c++, debugging, msdn, detours

I kinda want to leave this more as a thought experiment (I asked about it in chat but was directed here). But I can provide code if it will be helpful. Here is the scenario!

Process 1 is running and constantly debugging Process 2, I have injected a DLL into Process 2 and detoured one of the Windows functions it relies on so I can execute my own code. Is there a way from within Process 2 that I can prevent Process 1 from continuing to debug Process 2?

Comment: There is [DebugActiveProcessStop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679296%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I believe it needs to be called from within the debugger, so you would need a custom message handler or something that you could use to request the detach.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what do you excatly mean for "preventing debug".

You could avoid debbuger to recive any event related to your process, using NtSetInformationThread

```
push 0
push 0
push 11h ;ThreadHideFromDebugger
push -2 ;GetCurrentThread() // you can use it on every thread
call NtSetInformationThread
```

Reference:
Peter Ferrie anti debug tricks
http://pferrie.host22.com/papers/antidebug.pdf

Comment: By prevent debug, I was meaning literally stop the other process (Process 1) from debugging (Process 2). Maybe something like create a new thread that has debug privledges and have it start debugging so that the other Process is "kicked from debug mode", but I am fairly sure that won't work.